# Figuring out page url in Selenium (javascript:void(0);)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with this particular webstite [link to website](https://en.midland.com.hk/find-property/#list)

I'm trying to create a script that can go through all entries but with the condition that it has "memory" so it can continue from the page it last was on. That means I need to know current page number AND a direct url to that page.

Here is what I have so far:

```
current_page_el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'pagination')]/li[@class='disabled']/a")
current_page = int(current_page_el.text)
current_page_url = current_page_el.get_attribute("href")
```

That code will result with

```
current_page_url = 'javascript:void(0);'
```

Is there a way to get current url from sites like this? Also, when you click to get to the next page, link just remains the same like what I posted in the beginning.

Comment: When you click buttons on pagination you just triggers XHR which updates the results list. So current URL will always be the same

Comment: What exactly do you men by `the condition` as `has "memory"`? Can you update the question with the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: Memory means that it scrapes all listings from page 1 and saves as "1.pkl", scrapes from page 2 and saves as "2.pkl". If the script somehow crashes at page 21, the last file will be "20.pkl" and therefore in second run it has to go from page 21 and it will know that. That's why direct url is so important.